# Azure Http Trigger not triggering after .NET 7 upgrade

Tags: azure, azure-functions

My azure function was running on .NET 6 but I decided to upgrade it to .NET 7. I've fixed all the breaking changes as per [the guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide) and now when I run the function, it knows my function is available to hit but when I hit the endpoint, it just does nothing, just hangs there.

.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
      <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
      <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
      <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
      <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.8.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.10.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="7.0.3" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="7.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="7.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Method config:

```
[Function("Function1")]
        public async Task Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
```

Answer (score 0):

> My azure function was running on .NET 6 but I decided to upgrade it to .NET 7.

I have Azure Functions .NET 6 using the NuGet Packages `Microsoft.Graph` and `Microsoft.Identity.Client`.

[image]
[image]

**Function1.cs**

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace KrishNet6CoreAzF01
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        private static readonly string _clientId = "<App_Registration_ClientId>";
        private static readonly string _clientSecret = "<App_Registration_ClientSecretValue>";

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_clientId)
                .WithClientSecret(_clientSecret)
                .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
                .Build();

            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();
            var token = result.AccessToken;


            log.LogInformation("Hello Hari, This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.");
            return new OkObjectResult(token);
        }
    }
}
```

**.csproj file**:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Flurl.Http" Version="4.0.0-pre3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Auth" Version="1.0.0-preview.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.50.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

**Following this [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4?tabs=net7,azure-cli,windows&pivots=programming-language-csharp#prepare-for-migration) of Azure Functions Versions Migration, NET 7 Isolated AF with the same package and functionality**:

[image]

**Function1.cs**

```cs
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace KrishNet6CoreAzF01
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private static readonly string _clientId = "<App_Registration_ClientId>";
        private static readonly string _clientSecret = "<App_Registration_ClientSecretValue>";

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> RunAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_clientId)
               .WithClientSecret(_clientSecret)
               .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
               .Build();

            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();
            var token = result.AccessToken;

            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!" + "The Token is - " + token);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**Added program.cs file**:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .Build();
host.Run();
```

**.csproj code**:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.10.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0" />

        <PackageReference Include="Flurl.Http" Version="4.0.0-pre3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Auth" Version="1.0.0-preview.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.50.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```